# Applications that start with a system

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I've got an Arch linux and every time I start the system it opens applications, that I don't want to be opened. It starts me Ark, Mozilla firefox and the folder "download". Why does this happen? How to repair it?

Comment: Have you considered looking through KDE's settings to see if it sets up things to run on login?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying at the moment, but maybe there is a file responsible for applications with a system start?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `configure desktop` (or `system settings`), `startup and shutdown`, `session management`, and change `on login` to `Start with an empty session`.  If you want to remember applications going forward, you can change it back to `Restore previous session` next time you login.

If that doesn't work, go to `startup and shutdown`, `Autostart`, and make sure no applications are in there.